# When using bulk upload by loading data from csv file into postgresql database using JOOQ, onErrorIgnore() and onDuplicateKeyUpdate() are not working

Tags: java, jooq

```java
context.loadInto(table(entityData.getEntityName()))
       .onErrorIgnore()
       .onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
       .loadCSV(file)
       .fields(allFields)
       .execute()
```

I use the above  query for bulk uploading data by importing csv using JOOQ. But .onErrorIgnore() and.onDuplicateKeyUpdate() are not working. If I include .onErrorIgnore(), it is not ignoring or skipping the error causing record and stops inserting when an error is encountered. Record up to the error causing one are getting inserted.

If I include .onDuplicateKeyUpdate(), existing records are not updating and it shows
"ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE only works on tables with explicit primary keys. Table is not updatable"
even if the table has primary key

Comment: It worked but some errors like "ERROR: value too long for type character varying(25)" are not ignoring and the records upto error causing one are only getting inserted even if .onErrorIgnore() is provided. Also can we perform update based on unique constraint? I tried but it shows "duplicate key value violates unique constraint".

Comment: Can you report an issue here (with more details on how to reproduce this), if you think there's a bug? https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose